# How do you fix a broken type signature in a library for your project?

Tags: typescript, declaration

I'm using the `debug` and `@types/debug` packages in my project, and a recent update to `@types/debug` broke typings for code I know is valid.

Is there a way to cleanly fix the typing in my project using declaration merging so I don't have to wait for a fix to make it upstream or copy the whole .d.ts?

The relevant part from `@types/debug` is this:

```
declare var debug: debug.Debug;

export = debug;

declare namespace debug {
    type IDebugger = Debugger;
    interface Debugger {
        log: (v: any) => string;
    }
}
```

I added my own .d.ts file with:

```
declare module 'debug' {
    interface Debugger {
        log: (...args: any[]) => any;
    }
}
```

but now I get errors trying to use other members from the original declarations file: "Module 'debug' has no exported member' and such. It seems like what's happening is that once I add my own .d.ts file, it's not merged with the original, but it's used as the only declaration for that module. Why is this happening and how can I do what I want, that is merge the declarations correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot augment the signature of `log`, because it's defined as a function type. If it were defined as an interface, it would have been possible by adding an overload:

```
interface Debugger {
    log: Logger;
}

interface Logger {
  (...args: any[]): any
  (arg: any): string
}
```

So what can you do?

1. Install a different version of the typings and lock it (use the `--save-exact` flag when running `npm install`).
2. Override the types locally and keep using them until the definitions upstream are fixed. Ideally, contribute your changes to DefinitelyTyped yourself.

As to the second solution, since augmentation is not an option, you'd have to re-create the definition in its entirety and add your changes. The result could look like this:

**`debug.d.ts`**

```
declare module 'debug' {
  var debug: debug.Debug & { debug: debug.Debug, default: debug.Debug };

  namespace debug {
    interface Debug {
      (namespace: string): Debugger;
      coerce: (val: any) => any;
      disable: () => void;
      enable: (namespaces: string) => void;
      enabled: (namespaces: string) => boolean;

      names: RegExp[];
      skips: RegExp[];

      formatters: Formatters;
    }

    type IDebug = Debug;

    interface Formatters {
      [formatter: string]: (v: any) => string;
    }

    type IDebugger = Debugger;

    interface Debugger {
      (formatter: any, ...args: any[]): void;

      enabled: boolean;
      log: Logger
      namespace: string;
      extend: (namespace: string, delimiter?: string) => Debugger;
    }

    interface Logger {
      (...args: any[]): any
      (arg: any): string
    }
  }

  export = debug;
}
```

Such a declaration file needs to be included in your project.

Comment: Thanks! I did already submit the fix to DefinitelyTyped, for now I’ll stick to using one @ts-ignore since I’m wrapping debug in the project and only set this in one place.